# How to use the null- or notnull-operator with (complex) filter in Magento (1.9) API SOAP v2

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, soap, soap-api-v2, soap-api

**For example**:

- [sales_order_list api function](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html)
- [filter operators](https://www.fontis.com.au/blog/web-services-api-filter-operators)

**Possible solutions**:

- value = "notnull"
- value = ""
- value = null
- value = "true"
- value = "1"
- use simple filter
- anything else?!?!

Who knows?